# passing a value to an HttpResponse request

Tags: django, django-views

I have a urlpattern that brings a template that allows the fields of a model instance to be viewed:

```
(r'^display/(?P<id>\w+)/', display_record),
```

I also have a view function that allows a single instance to be edited. When the object is saved, it simply returns to the same template:

```
if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

After the save, how do I return to the display template, as opposed to refreshing the same view?
the code would look something like the following but I need a way to pass the object "id" to the HttpResponse request:

```
def edit_record(request, id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                a=ProjectRecord.objects.get(pk=id)
                form = RecordForm(request.POST, instance=a)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect**('/display/(?P<id>\w+)/')**
        else:
                a=ProjectRecord.objects.get(pk=id)
                form = RecordForm(instance=a)
        return render_to_response('productionModulewire.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. You already know what the ID is, so why can't you just put it back into the URL?

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/display/%s/' % id)
```

or, better, since it doesn't tie you to a particular hard-coded URL:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit_record', kwargs={'id':id}))
```